# Options for web apps on the desktop

Tags: webapp-rec

I am using Windows 7 and Firefox is my browser. I've been playing around with Mozilla Prism to bring a web app to my desktop, it works pretty well.

What alternatives there are?

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome also has a web application shortcut feature to separate a webapp out.

Answer (score 1):

[Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/about/) works brilliant for Mac OS X